# Writing and Reading Data

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, file-io, numpy

In my bin file data arrangement is `01 02 03 04`. After reading the

```
data X = numpy.fromfile(   ,dtype=uint32)
```

X becomes:

```
04 03 02 01...
```

Also, when `X` is like `01 02 03 04...` and write it to file using `X.tofile()`, the file content becomes `04 03 02 01`.

I need to write and load the array in such a way that I can get them in the same order, any ideas about what the problem could be?

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

You use little-endian processor, so the byte order will be different, I'm not a numpy user, but try:

```
>>> hex(numpy.fromfile('1.txt', dtype=numpy.dtype('>u4')))
'0x1020304L'
>>>
```

See more [Data type objects (dtype)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), by the way, the data didn't change see:

```
>>> # we stored 01 02 03 04
>>> numpy.uint32(0x01020304).tofile('1.txt')
>>>
>>> # we see 04 03 02 01
>>> open('1.txt', 'r').read()
'\x04\x03\x02\x01'
>>>
>>> # when you load it, it's the same data
>>> hex( numpy.fromfile('1.txt', dtype=numpy.uint32) )
'0x1020304L'
>>>
```